# Special Chars in Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, character-encoding

I'm developing a web app in asp.net mvc using jquery, the language of application is pt-BR and some characteres are not displayed correctly, like accented charcacters and 'ç' char. Insted of this, a unknown char is displayed on browser.

Is there any way to set the location on jquery ? Or on the file .js, .aspx?

I am not doing an ajax call, I'm writing a text in elements of html like div, hyperlink, etc... something like this:

```
$("#myDiv").text("Água, Açúcar, e leite em pó");
```

But in my div is shown: "?gua, A??car, e leite em p?"

I've set my globalization in web.config to pt-br, my html tag and meta tags to pt-br:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">  
<head>   
   <title>...</title>   
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">  
   <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br">
```

Is there anything is missing ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you have `$("#myDiv").html("Água, Açúcar, e leite em pó");` instead? Is it working this way?

Comment: It does not work html .html method!

Comment: Do you have `$("#myDiv").text("Água, Açúcar, e leite em pó");` in separate JS file or is it inside the same file as the rest of your code?

Comment: I have my javascript code in separate file! The solution was open the file in notepad save again with utf-8 format and now It's working! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Educated guess: You are writing the text in ISO-8859-1.

Try forcing the browser to display the page in ISO-8859-1. If the text shows up fine then, this is the reason.

Change the encoding of the file you are fetching the text from. You should have a setting for that in your IDE / text editor.

Comment: For the record: you should use utf-8 as your default encoding.

Comment: My visual studio is set to save in utf-8. I also try to save the .js file in another text editor (notepad++) but it does not work as well =(

Comment: @Felipe hmmm. Could it be the other way around then? What encoding does your browser detect for the page?

Comment: @Pekka my meta tag is set to utf-8, I try to change to Iso-8859-1 like you sugested but does not work. I think my browser is reading like utf-8 right?

Comment: @Felipe the meta tag will not always work if the server sends different information. Can you verify what the browser actually uses? There should be a check mark in the "encoding" menu

Comment: @Pekka I don't know what I am doing wronge, but look, I open notepad and copy the content of my .js file in a notepad and save a new file with utf-8 format. Now it's working but i don't know why! Maybe its need to work  with utf-8. I check my browser and it's with iso-8859-1. I didn't understand! So, thanks for help me.

Comment: @Felipe if the browser sess ISO-8859-1, then maybe your web.config is wrong  - the server may send ISO-8859-1 content-type headers. I'm not familiar with IIS though so I don't know where to fix that